# Using Twitter API to return number of tweets from an account

Tags: api, twitter

I would like to return the total number of tweets an account has using the Twitter API. Anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified a language, but per the Twitter API Docs, you call

```
'/users/show'
```

The element (json or xml) returned is 'statuses_count' which is the total number of tweets a user has sent.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554755/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-users%C2%A0show

Comment: Ok ... so what am I missing here ? <?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/seobpo.xml');

echo 'Location: ' . $xml['location'];

?> I only want the location. Btw ... does this have any prerequisites that need to be installed? I read something about PEAR ...

Comment: I'd recommend backing up a step and asking questions about getting PHP XML processing setup and then slowly work your way into the specific Twitter issues.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API 1.1 http request to use...

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=accountScreenName;
```

Decode the json...

```
$jsonOutput = json_decode($jsonData);
```

Below is where to find number of total tweets from the account...

```
$jsonOutput->statuses_count;
```